# How can I use underscore in listings package properly?

Tags: listings, underscore

I understand that underscore is a special character in LaTeX, but how can I input underscores within `lstlisting` blocks without changing the code block itself?

Here is a short example:

Settings:

```
\lstset{
    frame=l,
    language=C++,
    basicstyle=\fontsize{11}{11}\selectfont\ttfamily,
    aboveskip=3mm,
    belowskip=3mm,
    showstringspaces=false,
    columns=fixed,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{mauve},
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    tabsize=4,
    texcl=true 
}
```

Code snippet:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
shared_ptr<vector> p; // this is a shared_ptr
\end{lstlisting}
```

If you could provide an answer works for both `lstlisting` and `lstinline` could be the best.

Comment: I don't understand this question. What problems are you currently experiencing?

Answer (score 7):

Your problem stems from the fact that you have

```
texcl=true
```

as part of your [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) settings. Let's see what the [`listings` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) mentions about `texcl`:

> `texcl=<true>|<false>` or `texcl` (default is `false`)
>   activates or deactivates LaTeX comment lines. If activated, comment line
>   delimiters are printed as usual, but the comment line text (up to the end of
>   line) is read as LaTeX code and typeset in comment style.

Of course, if you have `texcl` set and `_` in your comments, then you'll be forced to adhere to LaTeX's rules for underscores in text. My suggestion would be to remove the `texcl` option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\lstset{
  frame=l,
  language=C++,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{green}\ttfamily,
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  %texcl=true 
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
shared_ptr<vector> p; // this is a shared_ptr
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you can use `texcl` but should be aware of special processing of LaTeX-related uses in the comments:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\lstset{
  frame=l,
  language=C++,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{green},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  texcl=true 
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
shared_ptr<vector> p; // this is a \verb|shared_ptr|
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```